# Writing in OCR-B, size 1

Tags: fonts, fontsize, ocr

I have a specification stating that I need to write in OCR-B, size 1. 
I am currently using the package `ocr`, but using the macro `\ocr{0123}` results in a font way to large, compared with a test PDF I recieved.

The assumed that "size 1" was a standard in the OCR-B font family, but how do I set it?

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example of code?

Comment: Also, can we get a link to the test PDF or, if you can't do that, the output from `pdffonts <name of test pdf>.pdf` (if you are on Linux) or the information about fonts provided by your PDF viewer's display of the 'Properties' of the test PDF.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is helpful as there isn't enough information in the question, but I was curious and this seemed interesting.

So with the default **ocr** package and type1 fonts from CTAN, I get the following output

[image: type1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocr,kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\ocrfamily
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

Looking for information about `Size 1` and failing to find it, I found [Ansuz's page](http://ansuz.sooke.bc.ca/page/fonts#ocrb) which includes a 'parasitic' package which is supposed to include cleaned up versions of the fonts in various formats, based on the original MetaFont sources. The documentation suggests that opentype is preferable if possible, so I decided to try that and got rather better looking results

[image: Ansuz's opentype]

by compiling the following sample with XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,kantlipsum}
\setmainfont{OCRB.otf}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

However, the visual improvement may just be an effect of the justification and it does not seem to have much to do with size. (If anything, this seems larger than the type1 version by default.) But the package contains documentation which may contain useful information.